# Creating a new entry in SQL in a join table is giving me null values

Tags: java, mysql

```
@Override
public Order create(Order order) {
    try (Connection connection = DBUtils.getInstance().getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection
                    .prepareStatement(
                            "INSERT INTO orders(fk_customer_id) VALUES (?);" +
                            "SELECT order_id INTO @newid FROM orders WHERE fk_customer_id = ? " +
                            "ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1;" +
                            "INSERT INTO orders_items(fk_order_id, fk_item_id, quantity) VALUES (@newid, ?, ?);");) {
        statement.setLong(1, order.getId());
        statement.setLong(2, order.getId());
        statement.setLong(3, order.getItem_id());
        statement.setInt(4, order.getQuantity());
        statement.executeUpdate();
        LOGGER.info(readLatest());
        return readLatest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.debug(e);
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return order;
}
```

Getting error in SQL syntax: near 'SELECT order_id INTO @newid FROM orders WHERE fk_customer_id = 1 ORDER BY order_' at line 1 -- when I try this syntax directly in SQL it works perfectly, so I don't understand?

For context, this is my readLatest() method:

```
public Order readLatest() {
    try (Connection connection = DBUtils.getInstance().getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1");) {
            resultSet.next();
        return modelFromResultSet(resultSet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.debug(e);
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

and modelFromResultSet():

```
public Order modelFromResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws 
    SQLException {
    Long order_id = resultSet.getLong("order_id");
    Long id = resultSet.getLong("fk_customer_id");
    return new Order(order_id, id);
    }
```

Comment: You've *already* been told that your ```readLatest```  method is wrong and *why* it's wrong. Also, you should be doing that double insert in a transaction in case of failure of one insert or the other

Comment: @g00se removing resultSet.next() just gives me an error though. Could you explain what you mean by that please? I'm still a beginner at java.

Comment: @g00se User asking questions, deleting, and re-asking?

Comment: @rzwitserloot It's a different question - before I was getting an exception, now it's giving me a wrong result. I tried the things mentioned in that question

Comment: ```modelFromResultSet``` needed as well please. Please update your post

Comment: Your very first `INSERT` statement doesn't set fk_item_id nor does it set quantity. Aside from that, code is doing really silly things - this should be in one transaction, and querying using 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' to get just-added data is not how to get auto-generated columns.

Comment: If you're going to do that, ```modelFromResultSet``` should be the only thing calling next() as in ```if (resultSet.next())``` (which should be the second line after ```Order result = null;``` )

Comment: @rzwitserloot Okay thanks, how do I get them then?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()

Comment: @rzwitserloot Changed my INSERT statements, however it's still not working, any advice?

Comment: Update your question, and never ask 'it is not working'.  Provide details. Compiler error? Provide it. Exception? Provide it. Unexpected result? Provide the exact input, the output you wanted, and the output you got. Also don't tag me specifically, why would I know specifically?

Comment: @rzwitserloot Jeez, okay, sorry.. only asked because you helped before and I was following your advice... And I did update the question before I tagged you.